# Browser extension / userscript to warn me when an e-mail I open in the Gmail web interface is being tracked by Streak

Tags: web-browser, email, gmail, privacy

I am looking for a browser extension / userscript that can warn me when an e-mail I open in the Gmail web interface is being [tracked](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/02/12/streak-gmail_n_4774889.html) by [Streak](http://www.streak.com/), which is a Gmail plugin that enables someone sending me email to tell whether I opened an email or not, without my knowledge.

Preferably, it would work with Google Chrome and block the tracking (i.e. makes it possible for the sender to see that I opened his email), ideally without preventing me from using Streak, as it would if I was using AdBlock to ban blocked 173.194.70.141, mailfoogae.appspot.com following this [forum thread](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21242).

Comment: Should it always block the tracking, or ask you? Should it let you send the tracking code later, when you want to let the sender know you have read the email?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Block the tracking, or ask me, both are fine. I don't need to send the tracking code later, that's OK it doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: If your antivirus is avast, it has a browser extension. It shows who tracks you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Gmelius](http://gmelius.com/), a Gmail extension that works with Google Chrome. Along with many other features (like streamlining the Gmail interface), it has a[n admittedly beta] feature which allows you to tell whether or not any service at all is tracking your email usage by a helpful little red eye.

[image: Gmelius' setting for enabling Tracking Detection]

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have just tested with Streak and it works great! (and it's compatible with http://oldcompose.com/)

Comment: After using it for a few more days: 1) I wish it said what kind of tracking is used (Streak, etc.) 2) Quite a few false positives.